# Need to add badge in nebular menu

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, nebular

I want to add badge in nebular menu for inbox count dynamically. Help me on this. Thanks

```
import { NbMenuItem } from '@nebular/theme';
export const MENU_ITEMS: NbMenuItem[] = [
  {
    title: 'Dashboard',
    link: '/pages/dashboard',
    home: true,
  },{
    title: 'Inbox',
    link: '/pages/inbox',
    home: true,
  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to extend the question and ask if it is possible to place a custom component or at least HTML tags within the menu item? Currently the interface allow only string (title) ...

The question above (about adding a badge) is just an example for the missing functionality - enable formatting of the menu item.

I would appreciate an example code to solve this limitation, even if it contains extending nebular framework classes.

Thx,
Yohay